# Lost in the Nether land and can't find portal to return?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son has lost his portal in his Netherland and he's unable to return to his creative world. I've tried to type in `/kill` but it's not accepting this code.

He's playing on his Samsung tablet. How do we get back?

Comment: Mr Lemon.... you are truly a life saver.... it worked! ... thank you .. thank you...  thank also to gerwin. My son will be so happy :)))))))

Comment: I have been lost in the Nether lands my entire youth :(

Answer (score 2):

You can change the game mode for this world to survival temporarily. I'm doing this on the Windows 10 Editon now, but the android version of the game should work the same.

1. In the main menu, tap <kbd>Play</kbd>
2. Tap the pencil icon next to your son's world.

   [image: Edit World Button]
3. Set the world to survival by tapping Survival

   [image: Changing Gamemodes]
4. Enter the world and take a hot bath in lava. Respawn in the overworld, rejoice, and quit to main menu again.
5. Repeat steps 1-3, only setting the world back to *creative* this time.

This is assuming that your spawnpoint is close to where you want to be in the overworld. In any case, finding your sons builds in the overworld should be easier than locating a nether portal in the nether.

Answer (score 0):

Press F3, I've read on multiple forums that the portal is usually located at, or around 0, 0.. if you still can't find it around 0, 0 start at that point and spiral outwards, you should be able to find it eventually.

Comment: thank you for your reply .  Ive tried 0, o1 0, 02 etc but nothings working.   All my screen is showing is <steve> 0, 01  am i doing this correctly?

Comment: start at 0, 0, excavate the area to see if it's anywhere near 0,0 if you can't find it go to exactly 0 . 0 and start spiraling outwards from 0.0 you'll find it eventually

Comment: Can i die in creative mode in the Netherland?  Im using a tablet?  F3 isn't working. .. i thought if i died i could be re spawned in my sons creative world? ?

Comment: @Gerwin this is Pocket Edition we're talking about. Commands are not a thing.

Comment: in that case, spiraling outward from 0.0 is his only option

Comment: Hi again   i did try /kill steve but it's still come up with error: command kill not found.  Ive now fallen thru the ground and im surrounded by larva  and there's no way out.

Comment: according to MrLemon commands do not work in pocket edition :(

Comment: How can he press F3? He's on a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

In such a situation, once you create a Nether portal make a second backup of the game to know the coordinates. Once done, go to the original world and go through the nether, make a chest there and add important items such as stone blocks, obsidian, and lighters. A plus point in the Nether is you can track the path you take by lighting the way. It's better than maps.

However, a good supply of lighters is required, whenever you go to the Nether make sure to have an empty locator map from the original point, carry a pickaxe because you can only mine soul sand with bare hands in the nether. If all else fails, I'd suggest never to bring the most important items to the Nether and just die if the portal glitches

Answer (score -1):

Switch to creative mode and make a 4×5 wall of obsidien with the six center blocks removed and hit it with a blaze charge this will make a portal back to the overworld. You wont be back where your original portal was but at least your out of enderland. A good way to keep from getting lost in the future is to keep plenty of blank maps with you (craft from 9 papers or 8 papers and a compass) and use them every time you reach someware new. It can be taxing to do this but it will pay off in the long run. Also if he is in survival mode and he slept in a bed before entering enderland and dies in enderland not only will he re-appear in overworld he will be next to the bed. Not sure if this helps you but it has saved me many times.